# ERROR en SQL: ERROR: no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «type_efficacy2» SQL state: 42830

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql-13

Estoy creado una base de datos para aprender, y me encuentro con este error:

> ERROR:  no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «type_efficacy2» SQL state: 42830

```
CREATE TABLE type_efficacy2 (
  type_id serial NOT NULL,  
  damage_type_id int NOT NULL,
  target_type_id int NOT NULL,
  damage_factor int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (type_id,damage_type_id,target_type_id)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE types (
 type_id serial NOT NULL,
 type_name varchar(80) NOT NULL,
 damage_type_id int DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (type_id),

 CONSTRAINT damage_type_id 
   FOREIGN KEY (damage_type_id) 
   REFERENCES type_efficacy2 (damage_type_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

Al añadir el `constraint` en la tabla `Types` es cuando me sale el error. Para evitar el posible problema de **PK** en `type_efficacy2`, añadí `type_id` al `type_id`. Aun así, sigue fallando.

¿Alguna idea de por qué?

Gracias

Comment: ¿De estas tablas, cuál es la padre y cuál es la hija? o ¿qué modelo E/R estás tratando de representar? Pregunto, porque más creo que estás creando la FK en la tabla que no es, pero es imposible saber sin conocer el modelo.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder usar `damage_type_id` como llave foránea en otra tabla, dicha columna **debe tener una garantía de unicidad en su tabla de orígen**, sea declarándola como llave primaria, sea declaŕándola como `UNIQUE`, que parece ser lo correcto aquí, ya que tienes una llave primeria definida.

Así debería funcionar:

```
CREATE TABLE type_efficacy2 (
  type_id serial NOT NULL,  
  damage_type_id int NOT NULL,
  target_type_id int NOT NULL,
  damage_factor int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (type_id,damage_type_id,target_type_id),
  UNIQUE (damage_type_id)
);
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE types (
 type_id serial NOT NULL,
 type_name varchar(80) NOT NULL,
 damage_type_id int DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (type_id),

 CONSTRAINT damage_type_id 
   FOREIGN KEY (damage_type_id) 
   REFERENCES type_efficacy2 (damage_type_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

¿A qué se debe esto? Imagina que no hay garantía de unicidad para `damage_type_id` en `type_efficacy2`, cuando haya más de una fila con el mismo valor, ¿a cuál de esas filas se va a referir la llave foránea en `types`? ¿Cómo se decidirán las acciones que guarden la integridad referencial, en caso de configurar acciones del tipo `ON DELETE / ON UPDATE CASCADE` por ejemplo?